# past pefect: hadn't planned to buy

Tags: past-perfect

Is "hadn't planned to buy" naturally used in the following? How does it differ from the simple past and present?

> John works in direct sales. If he tries to sell you something you **hadn't planned to buy**, say "No, thanks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hadn't planned to buy* is the most natural expression. It's a warning that the salesman will try to change your mind. The time reference of "hadn't planned to buy" is your intentions before you meet John.
Both *didn't plan to buy* and *don't plan to buy* put less emphasis on sticking with your original intentions.

Comment: I suspect the question is why the past perfect is appropriate when the reference time is the present.

Comment: What do you think about the appropriateness of past perfect, and the other tenses?

Comment: I agree the past perfect is natural here. I suspect there's something about the narrative quality that makes it so, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Thank you both for your contributions. Typical ESL books say the past perfect is anchored to past tense. But in many cases this principle (if we call it such) is overriden. I suspect this sort of past perfect is licensed when the narrative context is about general events or people in general. So sentences like warning people of phone scams are likely to use the past perfect that way.

Comment: Is the following equally okay? I have a hunch that it is not as okay as the OP sentence. 
Beware of John. If he tries to sell you the book he had written, just say "No, thanks."

Comment: @Apollyon So, about narrative and anchoring, maybe it's tied to an implied  past just before you meet John, and a more remote past when your intentions were formed.

Comment: @Apollyon I agree, in that case *the book he wrote* fits better, or just *a copy of his book*.